# How do i let my code add strings in Python

Tags: python, string

So for a project of mine I need to have my code generate a number of strings.

For example:

```
a = input("What is your favourite colour?")
b = len(input)
```

How do I generate `b` strings?

Comment: Welcome to SO Steven. Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do? What do you expect to get as "b strings"?

Comment: if len would be 5 for example, i'd like to get the strings : c1 c2 c3 c4 c5. if it would be 10 i'd like to get the strings c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c....

Comment: @steven what are you going to do with those strings? Do you want them to be empty strings? Letters of the colour?

Comment: I want them to be a letter of the colour

Comment: @steven, you want the user to only input 1 color? and then the `c`'s would be the letters of the color string? for example, if the user enters `blue`, then `c1` would be assigned to `b`, `c2` assigned to `l`, and so on like that?

Comment: @steven `b=[x for x in a]` will give you a list of the characters in the user's input colour.

Comment: Still feel like we're missing a part of your question. Given that you have access to all of the letters via `a` (e.g. `a[0]`, ..., `a[len(a)-1]`) why put them into different variables?

Comment: Because I want to process the letters and paste them back together afterwards so I end up with a different word/set of letters

Comment: and since some input could be very large (more than just colours) I want it to automatically add as much variables as needed

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this,

```
>>> a = raw_input("What is your favourite colour?") 
What is your favourite colour?5
>>> 
>>> b = ['c{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, int(a)+1)]
>>> b
['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5']
```

PS: Use [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) in Python3 ([`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) for Python2).

Comment: @m_callens, sorry for the misinterpret. Just updated my answer.

Comment: I think that OP might have meant, for example: What is your favourite colour? Yellow, and then generate 6 (`len("Yellow")`) strings. It is not really clear what those strings are supposed to be, so at this point you may as well do something as simple as `strings = [""]*len(a)`.